# My POST request only responds with source code, and not the correct XML response

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, post

I am trying to send a post request to a site using the Echo 3.0 web framework. My goal is to log into the site using a post request. I have looked at the requests using firebug, and can see that the website expects a post request in the following format:

```
<cmsg xmlns="http://www.nextapp.com/products/echo/svrmsg/clientmessage.3.0" i="1">
<dir xmlns="" proc="CFocus">
<focus i="C.21"></focus>
</dir>
<dir xmlns="" proc="CSync">
<e t="action" i="C.21"></e>
<p i="C.19" n="selectionStart">5</p>
<p i="C.19" n="selectionEnd">5</p>
<p i="C.19" n="text">username</p>
<p i="C.20" n="selectionStart">10</p>
<p i="C.20" n="selectionEnd">10</p>
<p i="C.20" n="text">password</p>
</dir>
</cmsg>
```

Firebug can also tell me that i'm supposed to receive an xml response. The issue is that I instead receive the source code of the page i've sent the request to.

This is the code I am currently using to send the post request.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://147.29.29.224"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//set headers
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/xml; charset=UTF-8"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSString *xmlString = @"<cmsg       xmlns='http://www.nextapp.com/products/echo/svrmsg/clientmessage.3.0' i='1'><dir xmlns='' proc='CFocus'><focus i='C.21'></focus></dir><dir xmlns='' proc='CSync'><e t='action' i='C.21'></e><p i='C.19' n='selectionStart'>5</p><p i='C.19' n='selectionEnd'>5</p><p i='C.19' n='text'>username</p><p i='C.20' n='selectionStart'>10</p><p i='C.20' n='selectionEnd'>10</p><p i='C.20' n='text'>password</p></dir></cmsg>";

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",
                   (unsigned long)[xmlString length]]
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[xmlString
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//create the body

//get response
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %ld", (long)[urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result); 
    //here you get the response 
}
```

The code gives me a response code of 200.

What am i doing wrong? Am i send the post request to the wrong page?

//EDIT:

I have figured out that I've been sending the request to the slightly wrong address, but am now facing the issue of a 400 response code, despite sending exactly the same POST request as the one that was submitted through firebug.

Comment: A response code of 200 means that your request was successfully received. What does `result` contain?

Comment: @Rob Result contains the html source code of the page, while it should contain an xml of the page after logging in.

Comment: HTML of what page? What does the HTML _say?_ Frankly, it sounds like you specified the wrong URL for your request, but there simply is not enough information here for us to possibly diagnose it.

Comment: Its tricky, for me atleast. The site is dynamically generated, so you're always on the same url. So there, to my unexperienced mind, isn't any other url to send the request to. I'll edit the post to add more information.

Comment: Alright, I figured out I had to send it to http://147.29.29.224/?sid=Echo.Sync, but am now getting a 400 response code.

Comment: 400 response is invalid request. Perhaps this would be better directed to the Echo support forums where they can better diagnose what the server is expecting and what you're receiving in response.

Comment: There are minor issues in your code (`sendSynchronousRequest` is generally ill advised unless you're doing it from background thread; you don't have to set `Content-Length` as that's done automatically; you don't have to instantiate redundant `NSError` object before performing network request; you're using `stringWithFormat` in a couple of cases you could just refer to the string literal; etc.), but all of this is unrelated to your error, which is clearly fundamental problem regarding the format of your request, which can only be answered by someone more familiar with the precise Echo API.